# Try to save to neo4j DB with new Neo4jClient in Core App

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

Im using the new neo4j Client from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4jClient/4.0.0.1-prerelease, now I would like to use parameters like from https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples

in my C# App and try to save a new node Person with:

```
    private async Task CreatePerson(IGraphClient client, params Person[] persons)
    {
            client.Cypher
            .Unwind(persons, "person")
            .Merge("(p:Person { Id: person.Id })")
            .OnCreate()
            .Set("p = person")
            .Return(person => person.As<Person>());
    }
```

I can run the Query but I didnt receive any Data and Im not getting any Error, what Im missing here?

Thank you and best regards

**UPDATE:** Added Return Statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing your query with the `ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync` method, which does not return results (and your code does not attempt to handle a result from the method anyway).

To get results, your generated Cypher must `RETURN` a result, and you need to use the `Results` method to get the results of the query. In addition, your code should actually use the result in some way.

Refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#returns) for more details.

Comment: Hi cybersam, Ive added a Return to  my create query but its still the same. What do you mean with result method? Thank you

Comment: That should have been the `Results` method, as shown in the documentation. I have corrected my answer.